# How to validate clone input fields using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

If i tried for single input values then the validation works but if i tried for more than one cloned input values then the validation doesn't works perfectly.please help me how to validate cloned input values.I checked so many sites but i didn't get proper answer,please help me about this.
Here is my html code :

```
 <div class="Box">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label ><span>Note Type:</span></label>
     <div class="input-group">                
            <label><input type="text" name="FirstName"></label>
     </div>
       <div class="input-group">                
            <label><input type="text" name="LastName"></label>
     </div>
      <div class="input-group">                
            <label><input type="text" name="height"></label>
     </div>         
     <div class="abc">
        <button type="button" id="num">Add More</button>
     </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
```

Here is My js code:

```
 $("#num").click(function () {
   var p = $('.form-group').length;
   var cloned = $(".form-group:first").clone(true).appendTo('.Box');
});
```

Here is my validation code:

```
var form = $('#submit_form');
form.validate({
    rules: {
        FirstName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
        },
        LastName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
        },
        height: {
            digits: true,
            required: true,
        },
    }, 
});
```

I need to get answer in this format.

Comment: Explain what "cloned inputs" means.  Show enough code to reproduce the issue.  Where is the HTML and where is the code that does the cloning?  You cannot "clone" the input fields as that will duplicate the `name` attribute.  Every field **must** maintain a _unique_ `name` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You should try another way to use validator plugin:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

**In this way, if you clone any field, rules will also be copied & it will work. :)**

Comment: ** Please note attributes added for each input/textarea tag. **

Comment: **No, this will NOT work**.  Cloning these input fields will duplicate their `name` attributes and that's how this will break.

Comment: While cloning, we can change the names. That should not be an issue.

Comment: However, your answer shows nothing about cloning or changing `name` attributes.  You merely show how to declare rules with inline attributes.